# How to store DLookup from [Form] to Table Field in MsAccess 2013?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, expression

I have two MS Access tables: *IdMhs* and *T_UKT*. I want to automatically fill in `[IdMhs].[SPP]` from some criteria in `[T_UKT].[UKT]`. I cannot  put it in query relationship, because the row cannot be edited on a form.

So I make a form and I get the number *SPP* (a textbox on form) automatically by using and it works fine:

```
=DLookUp("SPP";"T_UKT";"UKT = " & [Form].[UKT])
```

The problem is: the lookup value just shows on the form, and the results are not filled in the field in table (`[IdMhs].[SPP]`).

Any idea what an expression I should write to fill it in *IdMhs* table automatically?

Comment: `DLookup` is not valid. Please post actual expression used and not psuedocode.

Answer (score 1):

Need macro or VBA code to save value into table. If form is bound to IdMhs table, simply like:

`Me!SPP = Me.tbxSPP`

The real trick is figuring out what event to put the code into. You have a control (possibly combobox) where the UKT value is selected? Use its AfterUpdate event.

Why do you need to save the SPP value and not just retrieve it in a query that joins tables?

What is nature of table relationship? Is T_UKT a lookup table? If so should be able to include it in form RecordSource and then the SPP value would be available for display in textbox and DLookup not needed. Domain aggregate functions can perform slowly on forms and reports and should be a last resort option. The same code would be used to save the value. The query join should be 'show all records from IdMhs and only those from T_UKT that match'. Set textbox bound to T_UKT SPP field as Locked Yes, TabStop No.

Comment: im not put in query because it cant be edit if we got blank UKT, we cant put it number in query n in form too...

Comment: Here's relationship: the look up table is IdMhs.UKT field refer to T_UKT.UKT field. then in T_UKT i have SPP number , that i wanna to show if the UKT has selected from Id.Mhs table or form.

Comment: The fields of T_UKT are : [year]  ,  [UKT]  ,   [SPP] ... and the fields of IdMhs are : [Id]  ,  [UKT]   ,   [SPP]...  Here's the relationship: the look up table is IdMhs.UKT field refer to T_UKT.UKT field.    Then in T_UKT i have SPP number , that i wanna to show if the UKT has selected from Id.Mhs table or form.  The reason im not write UKT.SPP in IdMhs.SPP lookup field is : the SPP should be edited cause it would be change after a years, meanwhile the UKT is the permanent number.

Comment: Well, I am lost. Why would you use data input into T_UKT to change existing record in lookup table? Sounds bass-ackwards.